# Could not initialize canvas element using Express Application Framework

Tags: node.js, express, canvas, fabricjs

Just a spinnin' my wheels on this one.  I'm trying to get a start into the node.js/fabric/express world and can't seem to get past this wall of "Could not initialize canvas element".

I've created a new express.js application using the generator:
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Here's a simple working example of what I'm trying to accomplish within my express application framework:
https://jsfiddle.net/6dcgakb6/

I haven't touched most of the auto generated files, except to add jquery and a *public/javascripts/myApp.js* file for client side javascript.  It's within this file I think I'm having the issues or I'm not understanding basic principles.

I'm including scripts jquery.js, fabric.js, and *myApp.js* in `<head>` of my HTML layout in that order.  I added routes to *routes/index.js* so that I can include them using `<script src="fabric/fabric.js">`.

```
router.get('/jquery/jquery.js', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(appDir + '/../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'));
});

router.get('/fabric/fabric.js', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(appDir + '/../node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js'));
});
```

The body simply contains a `<canvas id="c"></canvas>` element.

Then, in *myApp.js*:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');                                                                                                                                                            
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({                                                                                                                                                  
      left: 100,                                                                                                                                                                  
      top: 100,
      fill: 'red',
      width: 20,                                                                                                                                                                  
      height: 20,                                                                                                                                                                 
      angle: 45                                                                                                                                                                   
    });                                                                                                                                                                           

    canvas.add(rect);
});
```

When visiting the page, I receive the error message:

```
jquery.js:2 Uncaught Error: Could not initialize `canvas` element
    (anonymous function) @ fabric.js:5989
    (anonymous function) @ fabric.js:7633
```

After playing around for a bit, I did find that I can run `var canvasEl = fabric.document.createElement('canvas')` without any error.  I can also run `var canvas = new fabric.Canvas();` without error as well (notice the missing constructor parameter value of 'c').

I would really appreciated some help on this one.  Again, I wonder if I'm missing a key design principle for including and initializing client side javascript using the express framework or if I'm missing something else  terrible simple.

I've searched for a solution, but have been unsuccessful in doing so.  Here are some interesting links I found along the way in case they are helpful to others.

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/573
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fabricjs/Qix_Z-2AJ2o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Facepalm*

Okay, it was a type-o.  I wrote `<cavnas id="c">` instead of `<canvas id="c">`.